# How can I access cache from another controller in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

$data = array('Product' => 'test','Price' => 150.23,'return_url' =>'111');

```
    $transaction_id = GUID();
    $cache = new Memcache();
    $cache->addserver('127.0.0.1', 11211, 3);
    $cache->set($transaction_id, $data, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 60);
```

I need to call this data from array in a function from another controller.

Answer (score 0):

**update:**
CI contains memcached driver not for memcache, so if you want to use memcache try something like this:

```
// to define the cache key in application/config/constants.php
define('TRANSACTION_CACHE_KEY', 'transaction_cache_key');

//application/core/My_Controller.php
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    protected $cache = null;
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->cache = new Memcache();
        $this->cache->addserver('127.0.0.1', 11211, 3);
    }
}

controller1 extends My_Controller {
    protected function getTransactionData() {
        return array('Product' => 'test','Price' => 150.23,'return_url' =>'111');
    }
    public function setTransaction() {
        $data = $this->getTransactionData();
        $this->cache->set(TRANSACTION_CACHE_KEY, $data, MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 60);
    }
}

controller2 extends My_Controller {
    public function getTransaction() {
        $data = $this->cache->get(TRANSACTION_CACHE_KEY);
    }
}
```

Comment: It tells me: Message: Undefined property: TEST::$cache

Comment: This array will be created dinamically from another source.